# data storage in android - combining SQlite with myPHP

Tags: android, database

I am trying to develop application in which i have data base on the server in phpMyAdmin which i'm taking data from with parsing json objects, of course different users have different data and some users share the same data. the problem is that when im taking the data from the server its taking too long sometimes and if i store it on the device it will more efficient but some users share the same data (they can delete and add data). so my problem is that - how can i combine SQlite with myPHP so that in the first time the user sign in the data wil be taken from the server and then inserted into the device data base and the next time the user sign in the data will be taken from the device data base. and if he will make changes it will update both data bases

Comment: What problem are you facing in achieving this?

Comment: i dont know the way to do that.. i have seen and read lots of tutorials about both data bases but nothing with combining them

Comment: I guess you have to replicate the databases, not combine them. right? And then, when changing one, change the other one also.

Comment: yes, but i also need to take the data when the user sign in for the 1st time from the server and then for the next time from the device, should i do with with storing boolean flag with sheared preferences?  and then when the on create to check if the flag is true or false?

Comment: yes, shared preferences is one of the good methods to achieve that. You can do that.

Comment: can you instruct the the best way to achieve all my requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to replicate database schema on both server as well as client.

Fetch the results first time from the server. and store it in you local sqilite. And then, store a flag in `SharedPreferences` to know in future that you have to fetch the results from local db.

After that, if any change in made in the local db, you'll have to update it at the server also. For that, it depends on your use case how fast you want to update on the server.

If you don't want it right away, you can wait and batch several calls and then post to the server using [Job Scheduler API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html).

If you want that changes on the server should happen as soon as possible, spin off a new thread and post them right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like that..

For different type of users you should send the data according to user name or any userid(which is send by user at request) and common data send to all users.

Now come to your's main problem..

At user first sign In request you will send all related data(On bases of userid/username) from phpdatabase(from server) to user and save all data in android device.

and when user does re-sign In that time you will check that android device database is null(have data) or not. If android device database is not null then you will not do a new request from phpdatabase for user data.

Now if user will have any change like you said user delete something or update something that time you have make a new request from android device to phpdatabase(server) for delete/add/update. and that first you will do a request from device to server(phpdatabase) for change on server side and if that service/request returns true then you will change/update that data at local/device database.